# Do I need to have Excel installed to use Openpyxl "interactively"? Can it interact with .ODS format?

Tags: python, excel, numpy, openpyxl, libreoffice

I have currently written a Python script that uses UNO to interact with a LibreOffice .ods document. However, it is very unstable and is causing a lot of system errors and crashing on Ubuntu 17.04.

I read through the openpyxl docs but I can't find the answer to this quick question: Can I use openpyxl on Ubuntu to *dynamically* manipulate a .XLSX or a .ODS document with embedded formulas?

I.e. I want to open the document, read data from the cells, update the cell values in a loop, read the new output data from the document's own formulas, and then load this output into a numpy array and close the document without saving it.

Does Excel/libreoffice have to be installed for openpyxl to use the embedded formulas in this way?

Thank you

Answer (score 9):

OpenPyXL doesn't need and cannot use a running instance of Excel. It doesn't interact with .ods at all. The closest thing to OpenPyXL for .ods is [pyexcel-ods](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyexcel-ods). The only practical way to evaluate Excel formulas is with a running instance of Excel. Likewise, the only practical way to evaluate LibreOffice formulas is with a running instance of LibreOffice.

So if you want to use OpenPyXL or pyexcel-ods "interactively", you would have to *not* use Excel/LibreOffice formulas but instead do all the calculations with Python.

If you need the formulas and you need to run it in Linux, then using UNO in some form (to control a running instance of LibreOffice) is probably still your best bet. Note that there are a few different Python interfaces to UNO, such as [PyOO](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyoo) and [UnoTools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unotools). I don't know what you're using now.

Finally, if the UNO-based methods are really too unstable, and you do have access to Excel, then you could try [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/). It would be fairly convoluted to get this to run in Linux (it might require a virtual machine; testimonials for Excel under Wine have been mixed at best).

Comment: OpenPyXL doesn't need and cannot use a running instance of Excel. - It means that Openpyxl will work if Excel does not installed in my system ? Openpyxl will read and write data in sheet ? Please confirm .

Comment: @Ravi K  that is correct. Openpyxl uses OOXML interface to directly interact with the xml files that make up an XLSX file. It does not use Excel in any manner as it's not required to use this interface. Thus Openpyxl can also be used on platforms that do not support Excel like Linux.